# Group columnar data from multiple arrays by one array and sum values per group

Tags: php, arrays, sum, grouping

I'm having this array:

```
$statuses = ['PROSPECT', 'BACKLOG', 'PROSPECT'];
$of_tranxs = [2, 1, 2];
$revs = [3, 1, 3];
$mgps = [4, 1, 4];
```

And I want sum by duplicate status. output an array like this:

```
array(
  'status' => ['PROSPECT', 'BACKLOG'],
  'of_tranx' => [4, 1],
  'rev' => [6, 1],
  'mgp' => [8, 1]
)
```

I'm using PHP 7.4

I have tried with the following:

```
$result = array_zip_combine(
    ['status', 'of_tranx', 'rev', 'mgp'], 
    $statuses, $of_tranxs, $revs, $mgps
);
```

then I foreach but the result is not what I want.

Comment: what should be the output for this [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] ?

Comment: Please share more details. What did you try so far? What keeps you from iterating over the four arrays in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the summing in the original arrays, then re-index and merge them after executing a single loop.  I expect this is rather efficient and I think it will be easy to read and maintain.

Code: ([Demo](https://ideone.com/dKnTBu))

```
foreach ($statuses as $index => $status) {
    if (!isset($found[$status])) {
        $found[$status] = $index;
        continue;
    }
    $of_tranxs[$found[$status]] += $of_tranxs[$index];
    $revs[$found[$status]] += $revs[$index];
    $mgps[$found[$status]] += $mgps[$index];
    unset($statuses[$index], $of_tranxs[$index], $revs[$index], $mgps[$index]);
}
var_export([
    'status' => array_values($statuses),
    'of_tranx' => array_values($of_tranxs),
    'rev' => array_values($revs),
    'mgp' => array_values($mgps)
]);
```

Or perhaps simpler by maintaining a new index incrementing variable: ([Demo](https://ideone.com/0jNPS0))

```
$result = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($statuses as $oldIndex => $status) {
    if (!isset($newIndex[$status])) {
        $newIndex[$status] = $i++;
        $result['status'][] = $status;
        $result['of_tranx'][] = $of_tranxs[$oldIndex];
        $result['rev'][] = $revs[$oldIndex];
        $result['mgp'][] = $mgps[$oldIndex];
    } else {
        $result['of_tranx'][$newIndex[$status]] += $of_tranxs[$oldIndex];
        $result['rev'][$newIndex[$status]] += $revs[$oldIndex];
        $result['mgp'][$newIndex[$status]] += $mgps[$oldIndex];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

Finally, if you don't want to keep track of indexes in the result array AND you don't want to perform another four loop with `array_values()` x4, then you can push reference variables into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DTjCH))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($statuses as $i => $status) {
    if (!isset($ref[$status])) {
        $ref[$status] = [
            'status' => $status,
            'of_tranxs' => $of_tranxs[$i],
            'revs' => $revs[$i],
            'mgp' => $mgps[$i],
        ];
        $result[] = &$ref[$status];
    } else {
        $ref[$status]['of_tranxs'] += $of_tranxs[$i];
        $ref[$status]['revs'] += $revs[$i];
        $ref[$status]['mgp'] += $mgps[$i];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: Really like your first solution 

Answer (score 0):

This solution will allow you to submit any number of arrays with values. They don't need to be only the four OP has specified.

The status positions have a reference to the other arrays, so for every duplicate in the statuses, we need to respect the corresponding position for the other arrays too.

I am assuming you will always have the same constellation, where the arrays with numerical values will always have the same length as the `$status` array.

Then I believe it is fair to make a function to handle those.

```
<?php
$statuses = ['PROSPECT','BACKLOG','PROSPECT'];
$of_tranxs = [2,1,2];
$revs = [3,1,3];
$mgps = [4,1,4];

function sumDuplicates($statuses, $arrays) {

    $dict = [];
    foreach($statuses as $i => $status) {
        foreach ($arrays as $key => $array) {
            if(!isset($dict['status'][$status])) $dict['status'][$status] = $i;
            $dict[$key][$dict['status'][$status]] = ($dict[$key][$dict['status'][$status]] ?? 0) + $array[$i];
        }
    }
    
    $dict['status'] = array_flip($dict['status']);
    foreach($dict as $i => $array) {
        $dict[$i] = array_values($array);
    }
    return $dict;
}

print_r(sumDuplicates($statuses, ["of_tranx" => $of_tranxs, "rev" => $revs, "mgp" => $mgps]));
```

The expected output should be

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [0] => PROSPECT
            [1] => BACKLOG
        )

    [of_tranx] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 1
        )

    [rev] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 1
        )

    [mgp] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

If you need only one array summed up or more, just edit the function call. You could do for example:

```
sumDuplicates($statuses, ["of_tranx" => $of_tranxs])
```

And that would only output the sums for of_tranx.

Comment: This answer doesn't guarantee indexed subarrays. https://ideone.com/r48i5v

Comment: @mickmackusa Totally missed that! Thanks for the hint, will update the answer right away :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    'status' => ['PROSPECT','BACKLOG','PROSPECT'],
    'of_tranx' => [2,1,2],
    'rev' => [3,1,3],
    'mgp' => [4,1,4]
);

function sumDuplicatesInArray($array) {
    $dict = [];
    foreach($array as $item) {
        $dict[$item] = is_numeric($item) ? ($dict[$item] ?? 0) + $item : $item;
    }
    return array_values($dict);
}
$final_array = [];
$final_array['status'][]  = sumDuplicatesInArray($array['status']); 
$final_array['of_tranx'][]  = sumDuplicatesInArray($array['of_tranx']); 
$final_array['rev'][]  = sumDuplicatesInArray($array['rev']); 
$final_array['mgp'][]  = sumDuplicatesInArray($array['mgp']); 
print_R($final_array);
```

Comment: i found problem, when (ex.) 'of_tranx' => [1,1,1] result [3], i want result [2,1]

Comment: @gadogtolis I misunderstood your question before. I updated my answer. Please have a look :-)

Comment: The OP's sample input indicates that there are 4 separately declared input arrays to be merged.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean to take the unique values of status and then add the corresponding items in the other arrays...

This first gets the unique values for the status and (for convenience) adds all of the other arrays to a single array to allow a `foreach`.

Then looping over the original statuses, it adds the values to a new array (created with `array_fill_keys()`) which acts to add all of the values for that type together.  Using `array_values()` to remove the index keys...

```
$statuses = ['PROSPECT', 'BACKLOG', 'PROSPECT'];
$of_tranxs = [2, 1, 2];
$revs = [3, 1, 3];
$mgps = [4, 1, 4];

$statusUnique = array_unique($statuses);
$arrays = [$of_tranxs, $revs, $mgps];
foreach ($arrays as $index => $array) {
    $out = array_fill_keys($statusUnique, 0);
    foreach ($statuses as $ind => $stat) {
        $out[$stat] += $array[$ind];
    }
    $arrays[$index] = array_values($out);
}
print_r(array_values($statusUnique));
print_r($arrays);
```

giving...

```
Array
(
    [0] => PROSPECT
    [1] => BACKLOG
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: This doesn't quite look like the specified output.

Comment: @mickmackusa, not quite - it's just a case of putting the right part of the generated results into the output.